# Why does C++17 if statement with initializer not work as expected?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, auto, type-deduction

```
struct A
{
    auto g1()
    {
        return true;
    }

    void f()
    {
        if (auto b = g1(); b) // ok
        {
            return;
        }

        if (auto b = g2(); b) // error: use of 'auto A::g2()' before deduction of 'auto'
        {
            return;
        }
    }    
    
    auto g2()
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

**Why does C++17 if statement with initializer not work as expected?**

Comment: You can simplify your demo to `struct A { void f() { g2(); } auto g2() { } };`. The if-initializer is a red herring.

Comment: I'm guessing here but is this caused by the same reason why we can call later declared functions inside a class? The body of a member function is checked after the class itself is checked. Because of that, `auto` deduction hasn't kicked in yet, because the function body isn't parsed yet. If you put `g2` above `f` it works fine.

Comment: @OP, I noticed you tagged this with the standards tag.  Does that mean you are looking for text from the standard to back up any answer that is posted?

Comment: @NathanOliver, Yes. That's just what I mean.

Comment: Okay.  I updated to use the language-lawyer tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the standard says so (quote from latest draft):

> [dcl.spec.auto.general]
>
> If a variable or function with an undeduced placeholder type is named
> by an expression ([basic.def.odr]), the program is ill-formed. Once a
> non-discarded return statement has been seen in a function, however,
> the return type deduced from that statement can be used in the rest of
> the function, including in other return statements.
>
> [Example 4:
>
> ```
> auto n = n;                     // error: n's initializer refers to n
> auto f();
> void g() { &f; }                // error: f's return type is unknown
> ```

To add a little bit of clarification, the "declaration" of `g2` is "seen" because the definition of `g1` is in the complete-class context. But that does not extend to having seen the definition of `g2`.